# How to set parent entity with only the parent id in Spring JPA when using JSON?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can someone please explain the right way to do this? I'm struggling to understand how to property deal with bi-directional one-to-many relationships in Spring JPA when it comes to creating child entities when all I have is the parent id.

I've pieced together enough to get it working by including a parentId in the child but that doesn't seem right and sometimes I have to set the parent object and sometimes I have to set the ID and I'm lost. It just feels like I'm randomly adding @JSONIgnore and @JSONBackReference until I stop getting infinite loops.

Let's say I have a parent entity

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Parent {
    private Sting name;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

and Child defined as:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Child {
    private String name;
    //I only want the parent id saved in the table
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I need to be able to create a child if I have the Parent object which is straight forward but I also need to create a child when all I have is the parent id and it seems like a bad idea to grab the parent object from the db just to put in the child when only the id is getting stored in the database.

How to I properly define both classes so that I can:

1. create/modify/delete a child if all I have is the parentId
2. c/m/d a parent with nested children
3. retrieve a parent or list of parents without having to get all the children
4. retrieve a parent with the children
5. if I retrieve a parent, avoid an infinite loop when the parent adds the children and then the children add their parent